# Firefox issues with visited links changing font-weight

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, font-face

Good evening guys, I might be going crazy here but I just noticed something that is going to drive me crazy now that I've seen it.

**Problem**
When I visit a link in a nav menu I'm building using firefox the link adds font weight (not much, like an extra pixel). It doesn't seem to do it in Chrome, IE 8, IE 10, or Safari at least not to a visual degree that I can see.

[pixel font issue http://www.pixelatedkarma.com/sandbox/personal/issue.PNG](http://www.pixelatedkarma.com/sandbox/personal/issue.PNG)

If you look at the picture above you will see that the menu item on the right is slightly bolded. It shouldn't be as all the CSS has the font (Questrial) at a normal font weight. I don't know if this is a Google Font issue or if it is a problem with how Firefox is reloading the menu item after it has been visited. Has anyone run across this? Or have an idea where I should start troubleshooting. This is a pretty foreign, and minor issue. Thanks

Here is a zoomed in comparison of the text from the two different links (top being the visited link and the bottom being non-visited).

[pixel font issue x2 http://www.pixelatedkarma.com/sandbox/personal/issue_match.PNG](http://www.pixelatedkarma.com/sandbox/personal/issue_match.PNG)

Comment: Image link not valid.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't liking it when I was adding http://. Fixed now. Also just to add onto it, I was trying different locally installed fonts and its still doing the same thing, so I'm crossing google fonts off as being the culprit.

Comment: Show HTML and CSS that reproduce the issue. Explain why you think this is a font weight issue. It could be a minor color change, resulting in different subpixels (depending on rendering).

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in Firefox Developer Toolbar to inspect the two links element to see if there are different CSS rules apply to it.

Do you also have any different css rules you done for a:visited?
Some styling are disabled for it, due to security issue [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector)

Comment: Nadda; everything is identical between both links code wise other then the individual classes which are assigned to them. And like I said, it works perfect in every other browser (was quite amazed that IE beat FF on this one).

Comment: @JohnSmith BTW try to change both link to the same word. It could be optical illusion :P

Comment: Nope there is definitely a difference. I changed the lettering on the Contact link to match the Company lettering. I then took another screenshot and compared both sets of text in photoshop. The same point in the "Y" differs in color - one is e5f2a5 and the other is d0d195. Its the strangest bug I've encountered in a long time.

Comment: Also I have been reading up on the styling being disabled for it but this is as if its either bolding itself without being asked to be (even if you force the font-weight:normal !important; on a a:visited) OR its giving off the appearance as if its stacked another copy of itself on top of its self. I'm going to start the stylesheet over from scratch and see if maybe its something else going on elsewhere thats causing it.

Comment: @JohnSmith can you by any chance provide a working link to this bug?

Comment: Well after re-writing it, it seems to be working properly now. Not sure what was causing the problem as the code is identical. So maybe it was some weird glitch in firefox acting up.